# NginX: Wildcard in location directive

Tags: nginx, regex

Gents,

I am trying to setup location block which has wildcard 'inside' regex. Here is what I think should work:

```
location ~ /documents/(.*)static=false$ { 
    proxy_pass http://upstream; 
} 
location /documents { 
    try_files $uri /test.html; 
} 
location = /test.html { 
    expires 30s; 
}
```

Unfortunately first location block is not working for me.

My testing URL is domain.com/documents/23/582ad23330d63a078c967bc3/-1476160403/DUH/POI/2016-12-13/params?variable=my&var=0&many=other-variables&static=false .

As you can see URI is quite complex, that is why I want to use wildcard.

Any idea why it is not working and how to fix this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with `static=false`?

Comment: static=false is a parameter in URL (check my testing URL). Sometimes it will be present so request should be proxied, sometimes not - request should be served from static page.

Comment: The parameters (or query string) is not part of the normalized URI used by `location` and `rewrite` directives. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html) for details.

Comment: @RichardSmith Thanks a lot! I've solved my problem :-)